# Ionic 2: How to do a total fresh install

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I believe i have totally messed up my setup for ionic and cordova, i was trying different solutions I saw online. Please how can I delete everything, **node**, **npm**, **ionic**, **cordova** etc, anything that has to do with Ionic 2 and start afresh

Comment: These are separate modules, if you really want to do that you should uninstall them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only a problem with your current project and not with the node/ionic installation in general:

The cleanest way to start with a fresh project would be to create a new blank Ionic 2 project with

```
$ ionic start myProjectName blank --v2
```

Assuming that you have not changed the build process (e.g. by [custom build configurations](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/app-scripts/)) or hacked something else, the only relevant folder is `/src`, where all your source code is. Copy this folder from the old to the new project.

If you have used any additional library, install it/them in your new project, too.